# React Native WebView - How to send JWT token in header to WordPress Site

Tags: react-native, jwt, wordpress-rest-api, react-native-webview

I'm trying to send JWT Token via React Native WebView's header like this

Note: *** The token is obtained from WordPress Rest API
(https://mywordpress.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token).

```
<WebView
     source={{ 
     uri: this.props.link,
     headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUz...'},
     }}  
     style={{resizeMode: 'cover', flex: 1}}
/>
```

It seems not working!!

Did I miss some wordpress configurations or perhaps React Native itself?

Thank you.

Comment: Its an open issue https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/18

Comment: did u get any solution